# What does the double colon stand for in the Qt documentation?

Tags: c++, qt, syntax

In the Qt documentation, I don't understand a syntax shown below:

Here is the syntax prototype of the function `addTab()` from `QTabWidget class`:

```
int QTabWidget::addTab(QWidget * page, const QString & label)
```

I don't understand why there are **two colons** after `QTabWidget`. I think it means that `addTab()` comes from the `QTabWidget` class, so if we want to use that function, we have to include `QTabWidget` (or any class that wrap the whole and include at the same time QTabWidget).

Is that right ?

But could we write that syntax `QTabWidget::addTab(.....)` in actual code or it is just a notation for the documentation to signify the class it comes from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand why they are two colons after QTabWidget. I think it is to said that addTab() comes from QTabWidget class, so if we want to use that function, we have to include QTabWidget (or any class that wrap the whole and include at the same time QTabWidget). Is that right ?

Have you ever programmed in C++? It's the [scope resolution operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator). It means that the `addTab` name is to be found in the `QTabWidget` scope; the documentation borrows how you're going to define that method (curious? [Have a look](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qtabwidget.cpp.html#_ZN10QTabWidget6addTabEP7QWidgetRK7QString)).

The scope resolution operator **has nothing to do** with which header declares that name (in Qt docs, the header to include is explicitely written at the beginning of each class' documentation).

Comment: Thks for explanation. I have had lessons in c++ but never have programmed in c++.So i have no practical experience,  I knew what  the :: mean but i did not understand what do they concretly mean in Qt. Maybe it's because i'm quite new to that, and so i'm not quite familiar with the documentation, but i have wait a few time to assimile it naturally and with your explanation it's now clear :)